# Custom Module Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

Drupal 8 question I'm having trouble creating a custom module The problem is that I am uploading an excel file that contains the shipping card numbers, and I choose the type of card by choosing from the list, but the card number is not withdrawn, and the number of cards does not increase in the online store after downloading Is there a solution?

no thing but i hope find answer